# Excel VBA Function Lookover - Cooccurrences of two values

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working on a user-defined function in VBA to find a certain count. For background, "raw" is a worksheet that refers a sheet that has genres in column B and an artist ID in column C. The sheet that I'm working in has combinations of two genres: first in column A, second in column B.

Anyway, the function that I'm trying to build should do the following:
Take two inputs as strings. Check the genre column in "raw" for matches with the first input. Then, take that ID and find a cell that matches the ID and the second input. If there is one found, add one to a running count. Whether or not it is found, move onto the next match. The function will return an integer that indicates the number of times the two genres had the same artist ID.

Now, my function is returning #VALUE.. no syntax errors, no compiling errors. Just the error in returning the value. I've looked it over, googled like crazy, and I just can't figure it out. I'm new to VBA, so maybe I'm just missing something really obvious or I've defined something wrong. Either way, I just need another set of eyes to look over it. Any suggestions for improvement are much appreciated, so thank in advance for your time and help!!

Here is the code. I know it isn't the prettiest, but it's short and the logic should make sense.

```
Public Function cocount(c1 As String, c2 As String) As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim cell1 As Range
Dim ID As Integer
Dim Count As Integer
rng = Worksheets("Raw").Range("B2:B183579")
rng2 = Worksheets("Raw").Range("C2:C183579")
Count = 0

For Each cell In rng
     If cell.Value = c1 Then
        ID = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        For Each cell1 In rng2
            If cell1.Value = ID And cell1.Offset(0, -1).Value = c2 Then
                Count = Count + 1
            End If
        Next cell1
        End If
Next cell

cocount = Count
End Function
```

EDIT: Thanks for viewing my question and being willing to help (And thanks Rdster for attempting a solution). I uploaded pictures of the raw data and the combination, although it won't let me embed the images. [Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RNHJ.png) [Combination List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTU4m.png)

Anyway, I'll try and explain my problem again. In the combination list of genres, each row contains two genres. I want to find how many times those two genres share the same artist ID in the Raw Data sheet. There are 181,000+ combinations, and 183,000+ rows in the Raw Data. Thus, the function needs to be efficient--something that I'm not incredibly great at doing even in other languages.

Comment: Will you post an image of your sheet? I don't make a habit of downloading workbooks from folks I don't know.

Comment: For reference, you need the Set statement when assigning range variables - Set rng = ... /Set rng2= ... (There may be other issues though.)

Answer (score 2):

[image]   [image]

This can be achieved using built-in several different Excel Worksheet functions.

### Excel Formula using COUNTIFS

Define 2 dynamic named ranges that will resize themselves to fit the data.  `Gendre_2` is defined relative to `Gendre_1` this ensures that the ranges are the same size.

> Gendre_1 = OFFSET(Raw!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(Raw!$A:$A)-1,1)
>
> Gendre_2 = OFFSET(Raw!$A$1,1,1,COUNTA(Raw!$A:$A)-1,1)

Formula

> =COUNTIFS(Gendre_1,A2,Gendre_2,B2)

Reference: [ExcelJet - Excel COUNTIFS Function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countifs-function)

COUNTIFS counts the number of cells in a range that match supplied criteria. Unlike the COUNTIF function, COUNTIFS can apply more than one set of criteria, with more than one range. Ranges and criteria are applied in pairs, and only the first pair is required. For each additional criteria, you must supply another range/criteria pairs. Up to 127 range/criteria pairs are allowed.

### VBA

```
Public Function cocount(c1 As String, c2 As String) As Double
    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
    With Worksheets("Raw")
        Set rng = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set rng2 = rng.Offset(0, 1)
        cocount = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, c1, rng2, c2)
    End With
    
End Function
```

Comment: I definitely understand the Countifs function--I was trying to figure out a way to use it in this context before I tried VBA--but honestly I'm lost on the dynamic ranges. The raw data image that you have is different from mine, so could you explain how you got there? The dynamic ranges make sense to me in the context of the data you have there (And so does the VBA code), so if I can mimic how you set up the data I'll be set. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Reference: [Excel Names - Named Ranges](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html) The Worksheet Function `Offset` returns a range relative to a range. Offset has 5 parameters 1)TopLeftCell 2) Row Offset 3) Column Offset 4) Number of Rows 5) Number of Columns.  `OFFSET(Raw!$A$1,1,1,COUNTA(Raw!$A:$A)-1,1)` defines a range starting 1 row down from and 1 columns from `Raw!$A$1` we use the count the number of no-blank cells in column A -1 because our range start at row 2 and then we make the range 1 column wide.

Comment: I need reading on the Offset formula--it makes sense in your raw format when referring to the given formulas. However, I've been messing around with the formulas to try and copy your raw format, and I simply cannot get it down. You have the two genre columns followed by the artist ID for a given pair, and I cannot get my sheet to match that format.

Comment: I *have been reading on the Offset formula.. sorry for the typo.

Comment: Hey, any update? I've been messing around in trying to acquire the format that you have for your raw data image and I have not been able to.

Comment: I put together a sample workbook and a couple of demos: [countifs_offset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l30whvw0vexlmez/countifs_offet.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to count the number of times that c1 and c2 = B# and C# where # is the same row.

```
Public Function cocount(c1 As String, c2 As String) As Integer
Dim Count As Integer, iRow as Integer

Count = 0

For iRow = 2 to Sheets("Raw").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  If Cells(iRow, "B") = c1 And Cells(iRow,"C") = c2 Then
    Count = Count + 1
  End If
Next iRow

cocount = Count
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Check the genre column** in "raw" **for
>   matches with the first input**. **Then, take that ID and find a cell that**
>   **matches the ID and the second input**.

try this:

```
Public Function cocount(FirstKey$, SecondKey$, FirstRng As Range, SecondRng As Range) As Long
    Dim FirstAccurance As Range, ID$
    Set FirstAccurance = FirstRng.Find(FirstKey, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, 0)
    ID = Cells(FirstAccurance.Row, SecondRng.Column).Value2
    cocount = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(SecondRng, ID, FirstRng, SecondKey)
End Function
```

test:

[image]